# Repeat a string multiple times in an assignment

Tags: javascript, string

With numbers you can multiply a number a certain number of times using the following code:

```
var y = 10;
var x = y * 3; // 30
```

Is there a way to do the same with strings with native methods?

```
var y = "test ";
var x = y * 3; // test test test
```

Or if not is there a succinct way to do this in a single line?

Comment: The duplicate can be applied to any string, not just single character strings.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
var y = "test ";
y = y.repeat(3);
```

And this would give you **"test test test "**

[String.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Comment: Didn't know about repeat! Thanks.repeat(3)

Answer (score 1):

What would be `"string"*3` in Python, can be done with `"string".repeat(3)` in Javascript.  That appears to be what you want.